# Why does fs.open return a number?

Tags: node.js, typescript, fs

I'm trying to use node/typescript to read a file using this code:

```
const openFile = util.promisify(fs.open);
write(data: Buffer, index: number) {
    if (!checkPieceIntegrity(data, this.pieceMap[index])) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return openFile(this.path, "r+")
            .then(fd => {
                const writeStream = createWriteStream(fd, {
                    flags: "r+",
                    start: index * this.pieceLength,
                    autoClose: true,
                })

                return util.promisify(writeStream.write)(data);
            })


    }
}
```

but when I try to compile with `tsc` I get and error:

`Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PathLike'`.

In reference to this line:

`const writeStream = createWriteStream(fd, {`.

The node.js docs say that `fs.open` returns a file descriptor, not a number so why does typescript think `fd` is a number and how can I get it to recognize it as a file descriptor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[fs.open](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback) returns a file descriptor (as an integer). But [createWriteStream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options) receives a `<string> | <Buffer> | <URL>` as its first argument, not a file-descriptor.

Check [fs.write](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_write_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback) for a function that receives a file descriptor and allows writing to the file.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I was just thrown off by the fact that a file descriptor is a number. What does a file descriptor represent? Is it just a location on disk?

Comment: @schu34 - A file descriptor at the OS level represents a data structure internal to the OS that keeps state about the open file on disk.  A file descriptor in C is a pointer to a data structure that keeps the OS level file descriptor and other state such as current write position etc....  The file descriptor number in node.js is an index into some sort of table or map inside of node.js that lets the node.js internals get the C-level file descriptor so it can call C file functions on it (which in turn get the OS level file descriptor) and carry out operations on the file.

Comment: @schu34 - It's probably just a number in node.js because node.js didn't have an appropriate type for what it actually represents.  Thus, they just went with an abstract number that the native code behind the file operations can turn into a real native code file descriptor via some sort of map or table lookup.