# fs.open returns 3 rather than buffer

Tags: node.js

I'm a novice with NodeJs but I've been following a tutorial on Udemy. The following gives him a buffer from open.fs. It gives me the int 3.

Error:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received type number (3)
```

Debug variables at breakpoint where error is:

```
err: null
fd: 3
this: undefined
```

.

```
const {promises, open} = require('fs');
const {readFile} = promises


open('./EventEmitter.js', (err, fd) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    readFile(fd, 'utf8')
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the mix of the promise-based versions of `fs` and the non-promise-based.

The [promise-based version](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_open_path_flags_mode) of `open` returns a Buffer that can be used with the [promise-based](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_readfile_path_options) `readFile`:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const {promises} = require('fs');
const {readFile, open} = promises // <= Using the promise version of `open`

open('./EventEmitter.js').then(fd => {
    readFile(fd, 'utf8')
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
})
```

Only the [non-promise version](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback) of `readFile` support using a file descriptor as input.

Answer (score 0):

The majority of that code is not needed, you can get a buffer by simply doing:

```js
const { readFile } = require('fs');

readFile('./EventEmitter.js', (err, res) => {
    console.log(res); // Returns < Buffer ... >
})
```

---

Here is a working version of fs open:

```js
const {open, read, stat} = require('fs');

stat('script.js', function(err, stats) {
    open('script.js', 'r', function (err, fd) { 
        const buffer = new Buffer(stats.size);
   
     read(fd, buffer, 0, buffer.length, null, function(err, bytes, buff) {
            const data = buff.toString('utf-8', 0, buff.length);
            // Here is your data.
        })
    });      
});
```

Comment: Thank you but it is part of a tutorial on how fs.open works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52618275/why-does-fs-open-return-a-number